# How can I reload a URL with a new query parameter with NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have:

```js
<Link as={`/app/create?keyword=happy`} href="/app/create" passHref>
  My words!
</Link>;
```

The URL I'm currently on is `http://localhost:3000/app/create?keyword=sad`

When I click the link, the URL does update, but where I have:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(router.query);
}, [router]);
```

it just shows `{}`.

How can I be updated when the `router.query` updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `nextjs`, as you use prop `as` in `<Link />`, it's supposed to be used with a dynamic route to fill the parameter.

For example, you have a page `user/[id].js`, then you use `as` to pass the argument:

```js
<Link as="/user/1" href="user/[id]" />
```

In your case, I don't think you should use `as` property, you simply remove that prop and pass `keyword` directly in `href`, then it should work:

```js
<Link href="/app/create?keyword=happy" passHref>
  My words!
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` gets as a second parameter a list of dependencies.

When you pass it the router object (which is a singleton) it won't recognize the change, because it doesn't make a deep check but a reference only.

Therefor, you should pass the query value it self.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(router.query);
}, [router.query.keyword]);
```

Comment: No dice - just tried this and `router.query` is still `{}`

Comment: Pay attention that you need to pass `router.query.keyword`